# Select an element with highest z-index using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a page in which i have multiple element with class `aaw` but with different zIndex.
Now i want to select the element which have highest zIndex and class `aaw`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: based on it's css property `z-index` right? (and not an attribute?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var best;
var maxz;    
$('.aaw').each(function(){
    var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);
    if (!best || maxz<z) {
        best = this;
        maxz = z;
    }
});
```

The result is in best.

[Demonstration (open the console)](http://jsbin.com/piyes/1/edit)

Comment: @DaveNottage I've just added a demonstration for you.

Answer (score 3):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A5FUL/31/

```
<div class="aaw" style="position:relative;z-index:1;">1</div>
<div class="aaw" style="position:relative;z-index:2;">2</div>
<div class="aaw" style="position:relative;z-index:3;">3</div>

<div onclick="test()">Click</div>


<script>
    function test()
    {
        var highest;
        var object;

        $('.aaw').each( function(index)
        {
            if ( index == 0 || $(this).css("z-index") > highest )
            {
                highest = $(this).css("z-index");
                object = $(this);
            }
        });

        alert( $(object).html() );
    }
</script>
```

​

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following;

```
var highestzindex = 0; 
var resultelement = null;  
$(".aaw").each(function() {
    var currentzindex = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);
    if(currentzindex > highestzindex) {
        highestzindex = currentzindex;
        resultelement = $(this);
    }
});
```

I have added a demo.You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/kCzge/)

Comment: This would find the z-index, not the element.