# get the top most jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a `button` and several `divs` that are converted to `dialogs`.

I move them around and stacked randomly, so one one of them gets the focus and the others are behind that one.

I would like to click on the `button` and get which one of the `dialogs` is the top most of the stack

How can I get that information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363723/select-an-element-with-highest-z-index-using-jquery

Comment: @Steve good thinking my friend, that might work

Comment: I believe that jquery adds a class to an element it brings to the front, maybe ".ui-front".  You would need to debug and verify this, but then you could also just run a selector for that class.